# Dialog boxes appear on wrong screen after standby

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, standby, displayfusion

I have 2 monitors. The right one is my largest, primary monitor. I have a smaller, secondary monitor to the left.

Normally, dialog boxes appear on the same monitor as the application that spawns them is on. However, after my PC has woken up from standby (S3), many dialog boxes appear in the top left corner of my left screen instead. This is very annoying.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit. I'm using DisplayFusion too.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue, or did upgrading to Win10 help, assuming you did that?